# What's the correct present passive form of "to lead"?

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, passive-voice

There are plenty of examples of the present active form ("Dave leads the team") and the past tense ("Dave led the team"), though I can't find any which clarify the spelling when phrased as "The team, lead by Dave, did stuff".

It's the last case I'm trying to understand. I *think* it should be "lead" (since it's a present tense), yet I would pronounce it "led" (i.e: with a short vowel sound).

(Meta: I'm not sure what to call this tense, hence the slightly clumsy question; it might be "present perfect", though I'm not sure. Clarification on that would also be welcome!)

Comment: The past tense and present participle share the form "led". The passive of "Dave leads the team" is "The team is led by Dave", where "led" is the past participle form. The same applies to "The team, led by Dave ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The team, /lɛd/ by Dave, **did** stuff.

The word pronounced /lɛd/ in this sentence is a participle. As such, it doesn't have a "tense" of its own, in the sense that we usually use the word "tense". We can change the tense of other elements of the sentence without making any change to the word /lɛd/:

> The team, /lɛd/ by Dave, **is doing** stuff.

In English, there are two participle forms. One is conventionally called the "past participle". This name is not meaningless: it is used with the auxiliary *have* to form the perfect construction, which can be analyzed as a compound past tense, and for some verbs the "past participle" used as a modifier has a meaning along the lines of "this happened to the modified noun at some point in the (relative) past", e.g. "a broken vase" is "a vase that has been broken" or "a vase that has broken" and "a fallen tree" is "a tree that has fallen". But despite the connections between the "past participle" and the past, **the participle is not considered to be a past-tense form in and of itself.** It is also used in constructions like the passive, where no past-connected meaning is necessarily present: for example, in a sentence like "I see that the tree is being **cut** down".

So there are a few problems with your analysis that caused you to choose the wrong spelling. The word /lɛd/ is not a present-tense form--one sign of this is the pronunciation, but another sign is that a present-tense verb just doesn't make syntactic sense in that context. Consider what happens if you replace /lɛd/ with a present-tense form of the verb *manage*: we can't say "*The team, **manage** by Dave, did stuff" or "*The team, **manages** by Dave, did stuff."

The use of the word "by" is a clue that this is a passive construction, not a perfect construction. "The team, /lɛd/ by Dave, did stuff" means about the same thing as "The team, *which was* /lɛd/ by Dave, did stuff." In a passive construction, [the main verb is always in the form of a participle](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922), so the correct spelling is "led", the past participle of "lead".

Comment: Thanks, I'd not thought about the comparison with "managed" -- that makes this really obvious that "led" is the right thing here.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> The past tense and present participle share the form "led". The passive of "Dave leads the team" is "The team is led by Dave", where "led" is the past participle form. The same applies to "The team, led by Dave ..."